# How to fill column values from specific rows of separate column - python

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, append

I have the below dataframe.

```
    tripid timepointid  actualarrivaltime   date    time      temp
0   4292837     I       299.083333      2014-04-01  04:59:04  NaN
1   4292837     H       316.666667      2014-04-01  05:16:40  NaN
2   4292837     G       320.466667      2014-04-01  05:20:28  NaN
3   4292837     F       323.066667      2014-04-01  05:23:04  NaN
4   4292839     I       376.783333      2014-04-01  06:16:46  NaN
5   4292839     H       386.100000      2014-04-01  06:26:06  NaN
6   4292839     G       389.116667      2014-04-01  06:29:07  NaN
7   4292839     F       394.466667      2014-04-01  06:34:28  NaN
```

I am having trouble correctly sorting my dataframe. I need to sort by date and then arrival time at timepointid I for each trip. The problem occurs because the tripid values follow no pattern.

I created a temp column to be filled with the time at timepointid I for each trip, so that the dataframe can be sorted correctly. However, I am fairly new to python and do not know where to begin indexing a specific column and row to fill every 4 rows of another column. Below is what i would like to create.

```
    tripid timepointid  actualarrivaltime   date    time      temp
0     0         I       299.083333      2014-04-01  04:59:04  04:59:04
1     0         H       316.666667      2014-04-01  05:16:40  04:59:04
2     0         G       320.466667      2014-04-01  05:20:28  04:59:04
3     0         F       323.066667      2014-04-01  05:23:04  04:59:04
4     1         I       376.783333      2014-04-01  06:16:46  06:16:46
5     1         H       386.100000      2014-04-01  06:26:06  06:16:46
6     1         G       389.116667      2014-04-01  06:29:07  06:16:46
7     1         F       394.466667      2014-04-01  06:34:28  06:16:46
```

Additionally, once properly sorted I would like to re-order the tripid's so that it can be easily sorted in the future. Can anyone provide me information on how to proceed? Thank you ahead time for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
i_time = df[['tripid', 'actualarrivaltime']][df['timepointid'] == 'I'].set_index('tripid')
i_time

         actualarrivaltime
tripid                    
4292837         299.083333
4292839         376.783333

df.join(i_time, on=('tripid'), rsuffix='I')

    tripid timepointid  actualarrivaltime        date      time  temp  actualarrivaltimeI
0  4292837           I         299.083333  2014-04-01  04:59:04   NaN          299.083333
1  4292837           H         316.666667  2014-04-01  05:16:40   NaN          299.083333
2  4292837           G         320.466667  2014-04-01  05:20:28   NaN          299.083333
3  4292837           F         323.066667  2014-04-01  05:23:04   NaN          299.083333
4  4292839           I         376.783333  2014-04-01  06:16:46   NaN          376.783333
5  4292839           H         386.100000  2014-04-01  06:26:06   NaN          376.783333
6  4292839           G         389.116667  2014-04-01  06:29:07   NaN          376.783333
7  4292839           F         394.466667  2014-04-01  06:34:28   NaN          376.783333
```